# how to use forkjoin from rxjs in NodeJs for multiple call using NPM request

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

I have to make multiple serialise call on server side in **NodeJs** using  [request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) , and **RxJs Observable**

I have array of Url Address like ['www.google.com','facebook.com']
When I make request to call then server get busy in event loop . I want to know when my last url call gets response so that I can send response to front end
here is my code so far

```
 const foo = Observable.create(function (observer) {
         res.writeHeader(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
         var str = '<html><head></head><body><h1> Following are the responses: </h1><ul>'
         res.write(str);
         let count = 0;
         addressesArray.forEach(function (element, i) {

         observer.next(element);
         if (some Condition) {
            console.log('here i want to call complete when I get last response')     
       // observer.complete();   
         }


         })
     })
```

and this is my subscribe function

```
     const subscription = foo.subscribe({
         next : addres =>
         {
             request(addres , function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

                     console.log(response)


                 }
                if (typeof response === "undefined" || typeof body === "undefined") {
                     console.log('No resp')
                 }
            })

     },
     complete:()=>{console.log('done')}


 })
```

how can I use [Forkjoin](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn each URL into an Observable and then use `forkJoin` to wait until all of them resolve:

```
import * as request from 'request';
import { bindNodeCallback, forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

const requestAsObservable = bindNodeCallback(request.get);
const observables = addressesArray.map(url => requestAsObservable(url));

forkJoin(...observables)
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

You could also you `request-promise` package that just returns Promises and you wouldn't have to use `bindNodeCallback` to wrap `request`.

Comment: what will be the response in subscribe I am expecting like this `function (error, response, body) {` for each observable  @martin

Comment: If you use `forkJoin` you'll get array of all responses.

Comment: how much parameter would be in .subscribe function @martin  I only has one which is type Object

Comment: I got that but Im getting exception  if user fill `http://www.facebook` just but in my case I have function for that

Comment: Thanks Martin for ur great help and time :)